# image in tooltip (r)

Tags: r, tooltip, r-plotly, ggiraph

is it possible to insert images in tooltips on charts produced with r packages OTHER THAN highcharter? e.g., plotly, ggiraph?

the reason for excluding highcharter is that the underlying js charting library is not free for commercial or governmental use

in his post on [how to insert images in highcharts tooltips](https://jkunst.com/blog/posts/2019-02-04-using-tooltips-in-unexpected-ways/), @jbkunst mentions that "in the tooltips you can easily render html, that means we can put images, tables even charts"

there is also a question answered on stackoverflow on [inserting hyperlinks in ggiraph tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468583/ggiraph-tooltip-with-hyperlink), so I guess there is hope...